# How to change this jquery script so it appears on load instead of scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on this site. www.runebs.dk.

I'm using this script to trigger the information on each project.

JS..

```
$('.showHide').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $( '#subHeadline .description' ).slideToggle(200);
    var currentState = $(this).text();
    console.log('state: ', currentState);
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.showHide').empty();
        $(this).text('(+)');
    } else {
        $(this).text('(–)');
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // firing toggleInfo when doc ready
    toggleInfo();
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.trigger('scroll'); // init the value
    $window.on('scroll', function(){

        var pos = $('#subHeadline').offset();
        $('.article-header').each(function(){
            if (pos.top <= $(this).offset().top && pos.top >= $(this).next().offset().top) {
                var desc = $('.description', this).text();
                var title = $('.h3', this).text();
                var year = $('.year', this).text();
                var button = $('.showHide', this).text();
                $('#subHeadline .title').text(title);
                $('#subHeadline .year').text(year);
                $('#subHeadline .description').text(desc);
                $('#subHeadline .showHide').show();
                return;
            }
        });
    });
```

CSS..

```
.article-header {
    display: none;
}
#subHeadline {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 22px;
    padding-top: 64px;
    height: auto;
    width: 600px;
    z-index:1;
}
#subHeadline .description {
    display: none;
    width: 280px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 28px;
}
#subHeadline .showHide {
    display: none;
    width: 280px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.year {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -19px;
}
```

This script works perfect, the only little change I want to make is that the information about the first project is displayed when you enter the site instead of as it now where you have to scroll.

I hope someone can help me. Many thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code :

```
$window.ready(function() {
      code here
    });
```

Comment: Try this $window.on('load', function(){ instead of  $window.on('scroll', function(){

Comment: I have tried that, i think the problem is that the div's is trigger when it hit the top of the content div. So if I change the `$window.on('scroll', function(){` to `$window.on('load', function(){` it will not be triggered..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

check the fiddle here [**Full Screen**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/h697225v/5/show/)

[**Js fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/h697225v/5/)

Jquery

```
    $(window).load(function(){

          var target = $("#section3") // this should be the target where to scroll
          $target = $(target);

          $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 1000);


    })
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment i have made some changes to your js and this should work

- onload of the page js checks the first child and gives the title desc etc
- onscroll if the scroll reaches to other post it will take its title desc etc

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  // firing toggleInfo when doc ready
  toggleInfo();

  var value = $(".article-header:first")

  var desc = $('.description', value).text();
  var title = $('.h3', value).text();
  var year = $('.year', value).text();
  var button = $('.showHide', value).text();
  $('#subHeadline .title').text(title);
  $('#subHeadline .year').text(year);
  $('#subHeadline .description').text(desc);
  $('#subHeadline .showHide').show();
  return;



  });

  var $window = $(window);

  $window.trigger('scroll'); // init the value

  $window.on('scroll', function() {


  var pos = $('#subHeadline').offset();

  $('.article-header').each(function() {
      if (pos.top <= $(this).offset().top && pos.top >= $(this).next().offset().top) {
          var desc = $('.description', this).text();
          var title = $('.h3', this).text();
          var year = $('.year', this).text();
          var button = $('.showHide', this).text();
          $('#subHeadline .title').text(title);
          $('#subHeadline .year').text(year);
          $('#subHeadline .description').text(desc);
          $('#subHeadline .showHide').show();
          return;
      }

  });
  ```

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you be more specific I don't understand how I can incorporate this to my script.. And the fiddle does not do what i want..

Comment: but on page load you want to scroll to specific section right?

Comment: No sorry if I havn't been clear. I just want the title, description and year. To be displaced when the you enter the site. Instead of you have to scroll down to it. Do you have an idea of how to do that?

Comment: I tried to add your script to see how it worked but it doesn't work.. I have just changed the #section3 to article-header. That should do it right?

Comment: i have edited my comment and added js try replacing it with you have added in the question

Comment: I wish i could vote but i havn't got enough reputation points.